# With a AC to DC converter can I put in DC to get AC?

Tags: ac, dc

With a old laptop power supply can I put in DC to get AC?

Comment: Insufficient preliminary research.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No... it only works in the AC to DC direction.

Comment: Please elaborate.  As it stands at the moment, this post is a bit thin for an answer on EE.SE (although the same can be said about the question).

Comment: You're right... But the question seems to indicate that a short, succinct answer would best serve the OP, and a longer one would most likely be an exercise in futility.